# Jenkins agent "invalid X-Instance-Identity" after SSL Certificate implementation

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins 2.371 instance. In order to be secure, I have requested SSL certificates and implemented it. Jenkins UI is now running fine use `https://servername.domain.com/`

The problem comes with the agents. I have imported my `jks` certificate chain into the jdk using keytool, so not a problem with the certificates at all. When I startup the agent, I get an error:

> SEVERE: https://servername.domain.com/tcpSlaveAgentListener/ appears to be publishing an invalid X-Instance-Identity.
> java.io.IOException: https://servername.domain.com/tcpSlaveAgentListener/ appears to be publishing an invalid X-Instance-Identity.
> at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:284)
> at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:744)
> at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:543)

So, it seems that the url advertised by the server is not what is expected by the agent.

For reference purpose (not relevant however), the keytool command to add the jks to the cacerts store used:

```
keytool -import -alias /tmp/jenkins.jks -cacerts -keypass 'Password' -file servername_domain_com.cer -storepass 'changeit'
```

As for agent startup. I have downloaded the `agent.jar` again, since the move to `https` then the usual:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://servername.domain.com/computer/agenthostname/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret @secret-file -workDir "/opt/jenkins"
```

The agent startup includes the `jnlp`. I say this because, the only articles I've found on a similar error, states that the `jnlp` path should be excluded, but sadly, that makes little sense, yet I did try it, however the agent now just retries connectivity as it does not get the expected response.

I do not have any reverse proxy setup, so that is not the issue either.

PS!! I did extract the `war` file and looked at the `java` file that presents this error, unfortunately finding something useful to help is rather tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I decompiled `jenkins.war` to find the relevant java files that is causing the error to help me debug the cause. The error is generated by the java file `JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java` line 284, which is highlighted below.

```
try {
       identity = getIdentity(idHeader);
       if (identity == null) {
         firstError = chain(firstError, new IOException( // The Error gets generated here
         salURL + " appears to be publishing an invalid X-Instance-Identity."));
                        continue;
    }
```

So, I found that the identity is not available in the header.

It is critical that a RSA public/private keypair is maintained.

So the simple fix was to simply install the plugin provided for this called [`Instance Identity`](https://plugins.jenkins.io/instance-identity/)